# Python module import latency in Conda env

Tags: python, conda

I was doing a quick experiment on import latency in Conda environment, here's the result:

```
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> conda create --name import_test python=3.7
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> conda activate import_test
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> cat .\import.py
import time

start = time.time()
import matplotlib
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> python .\import.py
20.404196977615356
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> python .\import.py
0.560875654220581
(import_test) PS C:\Users\hokira\work\src2> python .\import.py
0.6324305534362793
```

What's interesting is that even with a new instance of interpreter, import latency is significantly reduced from the second execution of import.py. I believe the high latency of 20s only happens right after fresh install of conda environment. Does anyone know what kind of cache is involved here? I'd like to understand this behavior to optimize my C++ program that uses python through pybind11, which is suffering from the high import latency today. Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is interesting. If you come back in another shell session, is the import still high-latency? or is it that once you've imported a single time, the environment always has lower latency (across sessions/reactivations/reboots)?